# What opensource solutions can be used to implement anomaly detection based on Riemann metrics?

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring

When Riemann used as system and/or application metrics collector, what are opensource tools can be used in order to implement anomaly detection monitoring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of 3 possibility (Not exactly Riemann metrics based, but around anomaly detection):

1. Outdated but the most efficient in anomaly detectionI know: [Shyline + Oculus from Etsy](https://codeascraft.com/2013/06/11/introducing-kale/) Both tools available from [etsy's github](https://github.com/etsy/skyline) as Skyline and oculus, check the network graph for more up to date forks. Best one I found is [earthgecko/skyline](https://github.com/earthgecko/skyline) with its [doc](http://earthgecko-skyline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)
2. Graphite and checking that the Standard deviation fits in the Holtz Winter's Confidence bands
3. ELK stack in version 5 with [timelion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/timelion.html) which, as above,  allow to compute a standard deviation and alert if it goes out of confidence bands with the proper license.

Comment: thank you for insights, Skyline looks forgotten (Latest commit on Oct 14, 2015), IMO there's much more to be done in this area, was wondering where the community putting efforts related to this area, Holtz Winter and stddev are too simple for something advanced but useful, Timelion looks interesting.

Comment: @rombob yes, there was a presentation announcing Kale V2, but it didn't see the light 'publicly' as far as I know. That's why I talked about skyline network graph on github, there's some forks with better love but nothing really "sure" as far as I know

Comment: @rombo updated for a skyline fork, I've been pretty happy with skyline, I don't know if eatrhgecko included the 'season' variation model (weekly/monthly patterns)

Comment: tnx, fork looks better, checkin